# How to implement overlapping effect in Android RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Does anyone know how to implement overlapping effect in Android `RecyclerView`.
I tried to experiment with `LayoutManager` and I tried to find any article or third-party libraries, but nothing.

I am saying about effect similar to this one (I'm not sure I know how to name it correctly, but you should understand what I mean): [Example](https://vimeo.com/143368320)